# Wordpress Mobile view Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, elementor, visual-web-developer

Good day,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPEhc.jpg)
I'm building an ecommerce website on wordpress
I have a sidebar on my products page but when on mobile view, the sidebar is seen after all the contents on the website.
Is there any way I can make a button that will be sticky and when its clicked the side bar will show on mobile view

I want it to lool like what's in the picture or the link below [enter link description here](http://www.portotheme.com/wordpress/porto/shop1/product-category/electronics/)

I'm using astra theme

Thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Let us know exactly what you have already tried, and include a clear outline of your specific issue with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you resolve the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can inspect your browser (right click - inspect) and check your properties in elements when you click the "sidebar" html tag.

On the right side you will finde the Sytles properties where you can try out your changes.

I guess you have to adjust the width.

Edit: If you work with elementor you have the possibility to add css code in the tab "additional css".

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking up the code from the inspect tool but wasn't sure on what to do

Comment: Okay. When you open the inspect tool you will see the area "Elements". Now you can click the icon at the top left and your mouse hover will show you the html content. Now you have the right html tag for your sidebar. With this information you can check your css and try out some combinations (i guess something with width) which can solve your problem.